# HAProxy only logging starting messages?

Tags: haproxy

I use a remote service for logs. The directive:
`log logs2.papertrailapp.com:41859 local0` correctly sends my logs to the remote service. However when I view my logs I only see the startup messages:

```
Proxy my-service started
Proxy my-service-2 started
Proxy my-service-3 started
```

Why don't I see any requests? What am I doing wrong? (I've manually testing making requests and triggering 404 errors but I don't see any results)

Haproxy config below:

```
global
  log logs2.papertrailapp.com:41859 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
  log-send-hostname
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  daemon
  maxconn 8000
  user haproxy
  group haproxy

defaults
   log global
   mode http
```

Answer (score 2):

Append debug to your log line for more verbosity:

```
log logs2.papertrailapp.com:41859 local0 debug
```

For more details see https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#8